# Java regexp groups replacements

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to transform the String

```
"m1, m2, m3"
```

to the following

```
"m1/build, m2/build, m3/build"
```

only by using `String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)` method?

So far this is my best attempt:

```
System.out.println("m1, m2, m3".replaceAll("([^,]*)", "$1/build"));
>>> m1/build/build, m2/build/build, m3/build/build
```

As you can see the output is incorrect. However, using the same regexp in Linux's `sed` command gives correct output:

```
echo 'm1, m2, m3' | sed -e 's%\([^,]*\)%\1/build%g'
>>> m1/build, m2/build, m3/build
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`([^,]*)` can match the empty string, it can even match between two spaces. Try `([^,]+)` or `(\w+)`.

Another minor note - you can use `$0` to refer to the whole matched string, avoiding the captured group:

```
System.out.println("m1, m2, m3".replaceAll("\\w+", "$0/build"));
```

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the problem from the other end (quite literally!) you get an expression that looks for terminators, rather than for the content. This expression worked a lot better:

```
System.out.println("m1, m2, m3".replaceAll("(\\s*(,|$))", "/build$1"));
```

Here is [a link to this program on ideone](http://ideone.com/jYnUA).

Comment: That's the way I was thinking of doing it.  But don't you have /build and $1 swapped?

Comment: @BlackVegetable Since I'm matching the terminator, not the content, the `$1` belongs at the end.

Comment: Nice. However this solution will not work if there are spaces between commas. E.g. for input `'m1 , m2, m3 '` the output would be incorrect: `'m1 /build, m2 /build,m3 /build'`. The second answer which uses `(\w+)` as a regexp can cope with this situation.

Comment: @miso Not that it mattered much, but the "space before comma" was easy to address (please see the edit). I liked the `\\w+` solution better, though :)